# Date format prediction by using sample of dates as input

Tags: java, date, date-format

looking for a method which takes a list of dates(of string type) as inputs and returns possible date formats.

> for example: input is ["01/02/2018","13/09/2018","8/11/2016"] then
>   output should be "dd/MM/yyyy".

this is one of the example. it should be able to return all supported date formats by java which best suits for the given input.

Comment: not possible if the input is not constrained, it can be anything!  if the input is constrained, then just try all the possible format

Comment: `"dd/MM/yyyy"` can't parse `"13/9/2018"`. What's the logic for choosing a pattern?

Comment: @ernest_k why it can't parse? I think, it will parse because it's not in MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: The problem is the missing leading zero, it expects 2 digits for a month but gets only one with `"13/9/2018"` (= `"dd/M/yyyy"`).

Comment: Aaah! how can i not see this! thanks @deHaar.

Comment: No problem, little things like this often fall through the cracks ;-)

Comment: Its a pretty difficult problem, its so complex, but actually, really good post, thanks for it. from my point of view, you can to write some modules per each date format, then by patterns check if every part contains valid value (like day 1-31, etc.), and you can try parse with try-catch or any other exception control mechanism, and also you can double check parts from result if its containing expected values- in sense of getDate - day part from string, etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t think such a method is readily available. You will need to code it yourself.

That’s possible, though it may not always be possible to give a unique answer.

Require exactly three numbers in the string and the same separators before, between and after the numbers in each string. Pick up the first, the second and the third number from each string. Find the minimum and the maximum of each. I am taking your example:

> ["01/02/2018","13/9/2018","8/11/2016"]

- First number has min 1 and max 13
- Second number har min 2 and max 11
- Third number has min 2016 and max 2018

The year is easy, that’s the number where min and max are within, say, 1900 through 2100. Choose limits that fit your situation. Month is the number that does not go above 12. In your example the second number is the month since the first has a max of 13. If none of the non-year numbers goes above 12, you can’t decide and will need to throw an exception or the like. Once you’ve decided year and month, the number you have not used, is the day of the month. Check that it is within 1 through 31 for validation.

For both day and month: If there is an occurrence with a leading zero (`01` and `02` in your example) *and* all occurrences have two digits, require two digits in the format, using `dd` or `MM`. Otherwise use `d` or `M` (which will print enough digits for the number and will parse both one digit and two digit input). Because in your example month is given as `9` (one digit, in the second string) and `8` as day, use `d` and `M`.

Final result: `d/M/uuuu` or `d/M/yyyy`.